# Fitting a Second-Order Exponential Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I'm sitting with measurements of radiation intensity over time on two unstable isotopes (in the same sample). The radiation is of two different energies, leaving me with a second-order exponential formula for decay - similar to the formula for exponential decay but with two terms, these being identical but for the different starting intensities and the different half-lives of the different isotopes.

```
f(t)=(I_0,1)*e^(-lambda_1*t) + (I_0,2)*e^(-lambda_2*t) %(eventually with a constant term as well)
```

There are numerous ways to fit the data to this function, but how do I get the uncertainties 
(for example in the form of standard deviation) for the fitted variables (the half-lives and initial intensities)?

Comment: have you ever used gnuplot(http://www.gnuplot.info/)? it returns very nice uncertainties; http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html in 7. the fitting procedure is described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [NONLINEARMODEL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinearmodelclass.html) class, you can get the standard errors of the fitted variables as follows:

```
fitFunc = @(b,t) b(1)*exp(-b(2)*t) + b(3)*exp(-b(4)*t);

%# leave off the semicolon for nicely formatted output
mdl = fitnlm(tVector, energies, fitFunc, initialGuessForBeta)

%# SE of coefficients
mdl.Coefficients.SE
```